# Android Studio: Could not compile settings file

Tags: android, gradle

I`m trying to open project on reinstalled Android studio and get this error. When trying make a new project also get this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\STES\AndroidStudioProjects\TuBelleza\settings.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'C:\Users\STES\AndroidStudioProjects\TuBelleza\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Can you provide your failing file (`settings.gradle`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Unsupported class file major version 60` means that Java 16 is [not yet supported](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13481).
Try Java 8 or 11 instead (eg. Android Studio's bundled version) by editing file `gradle.properties` and adding `org.gradle.java.home=...`